Minikube not getting started after being installled on windows 11 after installation of docker,kubectl
C:\Windows\System32>minikube start
W0719 09:32:32.201445   13512 main.go:291] Unable to resolve the current Docker CLI context "default": context "default": context not found: open C:\Users\prati.docker\contexts\meta\37a8eec1ce19687d132fe29051dca629d164e2c4958ba141d5f4133a33f0688f\meta.json: The system cannot find the path specified.

minikube v1.33.1 on Microsoft Windows 11 Home Single Language 10.0.22631.3880 Build 22631.3880
Using the docker driver based on user configuration

X Exiting due to PROVIDER_DOCKER_VERSION_EXIT_1: "docker version --format -:" exit status 1: error during connect: in the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.45/version": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.

Documentation: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/

i wanted to install the minikube and start but its not getting started i dont know why! i installed the kubectl via cohockaley and same minikube via chocokaley but its still now woring.
This is the erroe message im getting.

Hi, please see formatting help
